# Getting a python error "cannot reindex from a duplicate index" and a warning too "setting with copy warning" in the below code

Tags: python, pandas

```
        import os
        import sys

        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
        from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
        from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report

#kindly download the data FIRST which is required and then update the path accordingly for the variables you have to give the path 
# variable1 = pd.read_csv(r"give the path to the data")

        variable1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/hp/Desktop/NIFTY/TCS.csv") 
        variable2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/hp/Desktop/NIFTY/WIPRO.csv")
        variable3 = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/hp/Desktop/NIFTY/HDFC.csv")
        variable4 = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/hp/Desktop/NIFTY/ITC.csv")

        frames = [variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4]
        all = pd.concat(frames)
        print(all)

       price_data = all [['Symbol','Date','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume']]
```

First, for average investors, the return of an asset is a complete and scale–free summary of the investment opportunity. Second, return series are easier to handle than prices series as they have more attractive statistical properties

```
# sort the values by symbol and then date

        price_data.sort_values(by = ['Symbol','Date'], inplace = True)

# calculate the change in price

        price_data['change_in_price'] = price_data['Close'].diff()


# identify rows where the symbol changes

        mask = price_data['Symbol'] != price_data['Symbol'].shift(1)

# For those rows, let's make the value null

        price_data['change_in_price'] = np.where(mask == True, np.nan, price_data['change_in_price'])

# print the rows that have a null value, should only be 5

        price_data[price_data.isna().any(axis = 1)]

        days_out = 30

# Group by symbol, then apply the rolling function and grab the Min and Max.

        price_data_smoothed = price_data.groupby(['Symbol']) 
        [['Close','Low','High','Open','Volume']].transform(lambda x: x.ewm(span = days_out).mean())

# Join the smoothed columns with the symbol and datetime column from the old data frame.

        smoothed_df = pd.concat([price_data[['Symbol','Date']], price_data_smoothed], axis=1, sort=False)

        smoothed_df

        days_out = 30

# create a new column that will house the flag, and for each group calculate the diff compared to 30 days ago. Then use Numpy to define the sign.

        smoothed_df['Signal_Flag'] = smoothed_df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].transform(lambda x : 
        np.sign(x.diff(days_out)))

# print the first 50 rows


        smoothed_df.head(50)
```

up to here it is working but when i execute the below code then it throws an error cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

[image]

```
        n = 14

# First make a copy of the data frame twice

        up_df, down_df = price_data[['Symbol','change_in_price']].copy(), 
        price_data[['Symbol','change_in_price']].copy()

# For up days, if the change is less than 0 set to 0.

        up_df.loc['change_in_price'] = up_df.loc[(up_df['change_in_price'] < 0), 'change_in_price'] = 0

# For down days, if the change is greater than 0 set to 0.

        down_df.loc['change_in_price'] = down_df.loc[(down_df['change_in_price'] > 0), 'change_in_price'] 
        = 0

# We need change in price to be absolute.

        down_df['change_in_price'] = down_df['change_in_price'].abs()

# Calculate the EWMA (Exponential Weighted Moving Average), meaning older values are given less weight compared to newer values.

        ewma_up = up_df.groupby('Symbol')['change_in_price'].transform(lambda x: x.ewm(span = n).mean())
        ewma_down = down_df.groupby('Symbol')['change_in_price'].transform(lambda x: x.ewm(span = 
        n).mean())

# Calculate the Relative Strength

        relative_strength = ewma_up / ewma_down

# Calculate the Relative Strength Index

        relative_strength_index = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + relative_strength))

# Add the info to the data frame.

        price_data['down_days'] = down_df['change_in_price']
        price_data['up_days'] = up_df['change_in_price']
        price_data['RSI'] = relative_strength_index

# Display the head.

        price_data.head(30)
```

Comment: Something has gone wrong with your formatting and I can't figure out how to fix it. This is too much code; please try to produce a minimum reproducible example; show the actual error messages; and *ask an actual question* - writing "this code gives me an error" in the title is not sufficient.

Comment: i really appreciate your effort buddy but this is how it works....Run this code in a Jupyter notebook and you have to install all the machine learning packages which is required like sklearn, pandas and all the imported things as you can see in the code and you also need the data to run this code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uun2sGSVrY4mS2WqIq2tbn1RiE0yvs6m/view?usp=sharing. use the link to download the data which is required to run this code